# XSL: passing variables between templates

Tags: xml, xslt

Is it possible to pass a variable from one parent template to its child element ?

```
<xsl:template match="structure">
  <xsl:variable name="var"><xsl:value-of select="@path" /></xsl:variable>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="folders">
    <xsl:with-param name="var1" select="'{var}'"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

this template will match:

```
<xsl:template match="folder">
  <xsl:param name="var1"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="$var1"/>
</xsl:template>
```

You see I wanna use var as var1 in the matched template.

How can I make this work?

edit:
the structure is like this:

```
<structure path="C:\xampplite\htdocs\xampp">
  <folders>
    <folder name="img">
      <date>01/28/10 21:59:00</date>
      <size>37.4 KB</size>
    </folder>
 </folders>
</structure>
```

edit2:

```
<xsl:template match="folder">
<xsl:variable name="var1"><xsl:value-of select="../../@path"/></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="var2"><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="var3"><xsl:value-of select="$var1"/>\<xsl:copy-of select="$var2"/>    </xsl:variable>
 <th colspan="2" align="left"  bgcolor="#FF5500"><a onclick="foo('{$var3}')"><xsl:value-of select="$var3"/></a></th>
```

in the jscript function the string is without its backslashes. anyone knows why?

C:xampplitehtdocsxamppimg

Comment: That should "just work" - the question implies it isn't. No wait... the template name and the select= don't match in the code shown, you've got select="folders" and match="folder" with no 's'. Is that the problem or is that just an example?

Comment: check out my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/41530702/4251431

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can pass parameters to named templates that you call via `<xsl:call-template>`, e.g.:

```
<xsl:call-template name="name">
   <xsl:with-param name="param" select="xpathexpr"/>
</xsl:call-template>

<xsl:template name="name">
   <xsl:param name="param"/>
   ...
</xsl:template>
```

When you call a named template, the context node is the current context.  So to call a named template for child nodes, you need to change the current context by using `<xsl:for-each>`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="child">
   <xsl:call-template name="name">
      <xsl:with-param name="param" select="xpathexpr"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:for-each>
```

In your case, though, there's no need to pass parameters, since the variable that you're trying to use is something that's navigable to from the context node.  And you don't need to use all those variables (nor should you ever give a variable a name as useless as `var1`):

```
<xsl:template match="folder">
   <xsl:variable name="linkarg" value="concat(../../@path, '\\', @name)"/>
   <xsl:variable name="linktext" value="concat(../../@path, '\', @name)"/>
   <th colspan="2" align="left"  bgcolor="#FF5500">
      <a onclick="foo('{$linkarg}')">
         <xsl:value-of select="$linktext"/>
      </a>
   </th>
</xsl:template>
```

Also, I'd be tempted to use `ancestor::structure[1]/@path` rather than `../../@path`, because it makes the intention a lot more explicit; your version means "get the `path` attribute from the parent of the parent element", while my version means "traverse up the chain of ancestor elements until you find the first one named `structure`, and get its `path` attribute."

Answer (score 13):

When using XSLT 2.0, it **is** possible to pass parameters to child templates, by adding `tunnel="yes"` to the `<xsl:with-param .../>` at the callsite, and to the `</xsl:with-param .../>` element at the called template as well. Just do:

```xml
<xsl:template match="folder">
  <xsl:param name="var1" tunnel="yes"/> <!-- note the 'tunnel="yes"' attribute here! -->
  <xsl:value-of select="$var1"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="structure">
  <xsl:variable name="var"><xsl:value-of select="@path" /></xsl:variable>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="folders">
    <xsl:with-param name="var1" select="$var" tunnel="yes"/> <!-- note the 'tunnel' attribute here, too! -->
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

For further information, please refer to the section [`10.1.2 Tunnel parameters`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#tunnel-params) in the XSLT 2.0 specification.

---

## An extended example

With tunnel parameters, you could even do this:

```xml
<xsl:template match="structure">
   <!-- same as before -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="folder">
  <!-- Look, ma, no param declaration! -->
  <!-- ... -->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="date"/>
  <!-- ... -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="folder/date">
   <xsl:param name="var1" tunnel="yes"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="$var1"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Because of the tunnel attribute, the `var1` parameter is passed from the initial template through all intermediate templates into the `"folder/date"` template.

Just remember that the `tunnel="yes"` attribute declaration must be present both on the `<xsl:param name="var1" tunnel="yes"/>` **AND** the corresponding `<xsl:with-param name="var1" tunnel="yes" select="..."/>` attribute.

Answer (score 5):

Two problems with the `structure` template:

1. You are applying templates selecting `folders`, but have a template matching on `folder`. Either change it to `folder`, or if you have a `folders` template make sure that it passes the `var1` parameter value down to the `folder` template.
2. Your with-param @select uses `'{var}'`, which selects that literal string `{var}`.  If you want to select the `var` variable, then remove the surrounding quotes and curly braces and just select `$var`.

Applied changes to your `structure` template:

```
<xsl:template match="structure">
  <xsl:variable name="var"><xsl:value-of select="@path" /></xsl:variable>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="folder">
    <xsl:with-param name="var1" select="$var"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 4):

The exact code for the call would be:

```
<xsl:template match="structure">
  <xsl:variable name="var"><xsl:value-of select="@path" /></xsl:variable>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="folders/folder">
    <xsl:with-param name="var1" select="$var"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

Another way to access the @path attribute of the root node would be modifying your template to:

```
<xsl:template match="folder">
  <xsl:value-of select="../../../@path"/>
</xsl:template>
```