# xml bulk file editor increment by numbers

Tags: python, regex, xml, xml-parsing, auto-increment

I am trying to prefix the `TEXT_VALUE` field's values by a number in incremental way in all my xml files only the tags called "TRANSL" with **ID="Example"**. 
Currently I am doing it manually, but since I have several thousands of them, I think I should do it programmatically.

here is the initial version:

```
<TRANSL ID="Example">
    <TRANSCIPT>
        <REF_TEXT TEXT_ID="a680" TXT_TM="a24">
            <TEXT_VALUE>this is an example</TEXT_VALUE>
        </REF_TEXT>
    </TRANSCIPT>
    <TRANSCIPT>
        <REF_TEXT TEXT_ID="a681" TXT_TM="a25">
            <TEXT_VALUE>another example</TEXT_VALUE>
        </REF_TEXT>
    </TRANSCIPT>
    <TRANSCIPT>
        <REF_TEXT TEXT_ID="a682" TXT_TM="a26">
            <TEXT_VALUE>third example</TEXT_VALUE>
        </REF_TEXT>
    </TRANSCIPT>
</TRANS>
```

and here is the edited version of how it should look like:

```
<TRANSL ID="Example">
    <TRANSCIPT>
        <REF_TEXT TEXT_ID="a680" TXT_TM="a24">
            <TEXT_VALUE>1-this is an example</TEXT_VALUE>
        </REF_TEXT>
    </TRANSCIPT>
    <TRANSCIPT>
        <REF_TEXT TEXT_ID="a681" TXT_TM="a25">
            <TEXT_VALUE>2-another example</TEXT_VALUE>
        </REF_TEXT>
    </TRANSCIPT>
    <TRANSCIPT>
        <REF_TEXT TEXT_ID="a682" TXT_TM="a26">
            <TEXT_VALUE>3-third example</TEXT_VALUE>
        </REF_TEXT>
    </TRANSCIPT>
</TRANS>
```

how can I do it programmatically? is there any professional xml editors out there? If not, How can I do it in python, or powershell, perl, notepad ++, or any other, for example?

here is my script in python as a notepad ++ plugin:

```
def increment_replace(match):
    return "<TEXT_VALUE>{}".format(str(int(match.group(1))+1))

editor.rereplace(r'\<TEXT_VALUE\>', increment_replace)
```

but it is not working...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the current count/`position()` of the `<TEXT_VALUE>` elements you can refer to the count/`position()` of the parent `<TRANSCIPT>` element.

To pass this count to the subsequent templates [I used the solution from this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4220609/1305969) and incorporated its approach in the *identity template* now passing a `num` parameter containing some value. The `num` parameter is generated in a `<for-each>` loop above all `<TRANSCIPT>` elements and passed down the `<apply-templates>` hierarchy to be used in the `TEXT_VALUE` template (everywhere else it's just ignored).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <!-- modified identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:param name="num" />
    <xsl:copy>  
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
        <xsl:with-param name="num" select="$num"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="TRANSL">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:for-each select="TRANSCIPT">
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates>
          <xsl:with-param name="num" select="position()" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each>    
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="TEXT_VALUE[../../../@ID='Example']">   <!-- added after extension of question -->
    <xsl:param name="num" />
    <xsl:element name="TEXT_VALUE">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat($num,'-',text())" />
    </xsl:element>        
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDIT:**
After the requirements have been extended in a comment I added a predicate to the `TEXT_VALUE` template modifying the matching rule to only select `TEXT_VALUE` elements which have an `@ID` attribute with the value "Example".

Comment: how should I run this? i am new to this environment... how can I run this to do this replacing job in all my files?

Comment: @cplus: You can use any XSLT-1.0 processor for this job. Which one depends on your OS. On any Linux variant you can use e.g. `xsltproc` which is often part of the default installation. But there are many others for Windows and Mac, too. An OS independent one is [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) which is written in Java and also XSLT-2.0 capable.

Comment: @cplus: If you pass the filenames via a _bash script_/_batch file_ this task should be done in a minute.

Comment: by the way, shouldn't the `<xsl:template match="TEXT_VALUE">` be this one instead `<xsl:template match="REF_TEXT">` ? or i am missing something?

Comment: @cplus: That depends on which node you want to replace. In the example given your want to replace the `TEXT_VALUE/text()` node by another value - so it is designed to replace that node. (I admit that this template is beyond beginner's scope).

Comment: Actually, I want to do the replace job only in TRANSL nodes that have  ID="Example", not all TRANSL tags. if i am not mistaken, this is doing to all of the TRANSL s, right?

Comment: @cplus - this answer is an [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt) script, a special-purpose language designed to transform XML files. In Python or any other general-purpose language (Java, PHP, VB) you can use a library that can run XSLT on XML sources. In Python, you can use the third-party module, `lxml`, to run XSLT 1.0 scripts iterating through all thousands of files.

Comment: @cplus: I extended my answer.

Comment: thanks for this comprehensive and accurate answer. Is it possible to give some indications on how to do it under bash for a folder that contains all of the desired files? thanks in advance

Comment: Yes. Use `for i in *.xml; do xsltproc xsltfilename.xslt $i; done;` with _xsltfilename_ denoting the XSLT code of my answer.

Comment: @zx485 should this be .sh file or .bat file? it says that "i was unexpected at this time." i am using .bat file.. please help. thanks

Comment: @cplus:In your last comment you asked for a bash command, so I gave you one.

Comment: @zx485 thanks it is working, but it is not saving (overwriting the files, it is just displaying on the terminal... do you have any idea of how to overwrite them..?

Comment: [xsltproc's](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html) `-o` argument saves transformation to file.

Comment: @cplus: @Parfait is right. So use something like `for i in *.xml; do xsltproc xsltfilename.xslt -o $i.res $i; done;` to convert all `.xml` files to `.xml.res` files.

Answer (score 2):

To add to @zx485 with a variant XSLT script using the `count(preceding-sibling::*)`, consider the following Python solution using `lxml`. As information, [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) being a special-purpose language to transform XML files can be a handy tool to manipulate your initial XML files to final end use format.

With Python being a general-purpose languge, you can leverage its `os` filesystem module and third-party module [lxml](http://lxml.de/) (a fully-compliant W3C library with XPath 1.0 and XSLT 1.0 capability) to iteratively create the needed outputs.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file to be parsed in Python)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Identity Transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Add Incremenet Number to Text -->
  <xsl:template match="TEXT_VALUE[ancestor::TRANSL/@ID='Example']">
    <xsl:copy>      
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(count(ancestor::TRANSCIPT/preceding-sibling::TRANSCIPT)+1, '-', text())"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Python**

```
import os
import lxml.etree as et

# CHANGE DIRECTORY
os.chdir('/path/to/raw/XML/files')

# LOAD XSLT SCRIPT AND INITIALIZE TRANSFORMER
xslt = et.parse('/path/to/XSLT_Script.xsl')
transform = et.XSLT(xslt)

for file in os.listdir():
   if file.endswith('.xml'):

      # LOAD SOURCE XML
      dom = et.parse(file)

      # TRANSFORM TO NEW TREE
      newdom = transform(dom)

      # SAVE TO FILE (SAME NAME WITH _new SUFFIX)
      with open(file.replace('.xml', '_new.xml'), 'wb') as f:
          f.write(newdom)
```