# Passing values from one template to another

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am trying to passing a value from one Template to another template. Although I found couple of example in this forum but I'm simply unable to make it.

Below is my XML:

```
<pi:PayGroup xmlns:pi="urn:com.sample/file">
    <pi:Header>
        <pi:Version>17</pi:Version>
        <pi:Payroll_Company_Name>ABCD</pi:Payroll_Company_Name>
        <pi:Pay_Group_ID>0307</pi:Pay_Group_ID>
    </pi:Header>
    <pi:Employee>
        <pi:Summary>
            <pi:Employee_ID>12345678</pi:Employee_ID>
            <pi:Name>Test Employee</pi:Name>
        </pi:Summary>
        <pi:Position>
            <pi:Business_Title>Lead Learning Specialist</pi:Business_Title>
            <pi:Worker_Type>P</pi:Worker_Type>
            <pi:Position_Time_Type>Full_time</pi:Position_Time_Type>
            <pi:Compensation_Effective_Date>2017-07-01</pi:Compensation_Effective_Date>
            <pi:Base_Pay_Currency>EUR</pi:Base_Pay_Currency>
            <pi:Base_Pay_Frequency>4-Weekly</pi:Base_Pay_Frequency>
            <pi:Organization_One>0307_3075999496</pi:Organization_One>
            <pi:Organization_Two>0307</pi:Organization_Two>
            <pi:Supervisor_ID>00295975</pi:Supervisor_ID>
            <pi:Supervisor_Name>Simba Sang (98765432)</pi:Supervisor_Name>
        </pi:Position>
        <pi:Earnings>
            <pi:Start_Date>2017-02-06</pi:Start_Date>
            <pi:Currency>EUR</pi:Currency>
        </pi:Earnings>
    </pi:Employee>
</pi:PayGroup>
```

Below is the XSLT which is in use for a long time:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:pi="urn:com.workday/picof"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>  
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- 00123456 ... 123456 -->
    <xsl:template match="pi:Employee_ID">
        <pi:Employee_ID>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,3)"/>
        </pi:Employee_ID>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="pi:Supervisor_ID">
        <pi:Supervisor_ID>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,3)"/>
        </pi:Supervisor_ID>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="pi:Supervisor_Name">
        <pi:Supervisor_Name>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before(.,'('))"/>
        </pi:Supervisor_Name>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="pi:Organization_One">
        <pi:Organization_One>
            <xsl:value-of select="if(contains(.,'_'))
                then(normalize-space(substring-after(.,'_')))
                else(.)"/>
        </pi:Organization_One>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Ask here is that /pi:position/pi:Compensation_Effective_Date value should also be passed under /pi:Earnings_Deductions/pi:Start_Date tag

pi:Start_Date should have same value as pi:Compensation_Effective_Date.

So I modified the XSLT to include two more template match one for pi:Compensation_Effective_Date and other one for /pi:Start_Date as shown below:

```
<xsl:template match="/pi:Compensation_Effective_Date">
    <xsl:param name="test"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:with-param name="test" select="."/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <pi:Compensation_Effective_Date><xsl:value-of select="$test"/></pi:Compensation_Effective_Date>        
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="pi:Start_Date">
    <xsl:param name="test"/>
    <pi:Start_Date><xsl:value-of select="$test"/></pi:Start_Date>
</xsl:template>
```

Had a param value in pi:compensation_effective_date template and passed that param to pi:start_date template. But the pi:Start_Date is always blank; how can I get compensation_effective_Date value in start_date as well?

Expected Output:

```
<pi:Position>
    <pi:Business_Title>...</pi:Business_Title>
    <pi:Worker_Type>..</pi:Worker_Type>
    <pi:Position_Time_Type>..</pi:Position_Time_Type>
    <pi:Compensation_Effective_Date>2017-07-01</pi:Compensation_Effective_Date>
    <pi:Base_Pay_Currency>..</pi:Base_Pay_Currency>
    <pi:Base_Pay_Frequency>...</pi:Base_Pay_Frequency>
    <pi:Organization_One>....</pi:Organization_One>
    <pi:Organization_Two>....</pi:Organization_Two>
    <pi:Supervisor_ID>....</pi:Supervisor_ID>
    <pi:Supervisor_Name>.....</pi:Supervisor_Name>
</pi:Position>
<pi:Earnings>
    <pi:Start_Date>2017-07-01</pi:Start_Date>
    <pi:Currency>...</pi:Currency>
</pi:Earnings>
```

Comment: I suggest you reduce the example to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem  - see: [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

"*In the absence of a select attribute, the `xsl:apply-templates` instruction processes all of the children of the current node [...]*" ([W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Applying-Template-Rules)).
This means your template matching `<Start_Date>` cannot work in context of `<Compensation_Effective_Date>` because there is no `<Start_Date>` child element in it.
Instead, the `<Start_Date>` template - like the other templates - just matches the content and is applied without parameters, which is why `<Start_Date>` is empty in your output.

I couldn't get it to work the way you intended, but I might have a few hints to get you going.
For the following code-snippets, note that I removed the pi: namespace because it caused trouble in my editor.

**1.) Easy solution**

It is possible to simply refer to the desired source element even if it is outside of the current context. This will produce the desired output:

```
<xsl:template match="Start_Date">
    <Start_Date><xsl:value-of select="../../Position/Compensation_Effective_Date"/></Start_Date>
</xsl:template>
```

Be careful using this however, e.g. in case an employee can have more than one position-element.

**2.) Using `<xls:call-template>` and parameter**

I adjusted the "call-template-syntax" from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2169304/4451272) to fit your example.

```
<xsl:template match="Employee">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy> 
    <xsl:call-template name="t">
        <xsl:with-param name="p" select="Position/Compensation_Effective_Date"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="t">
    <xsl:param name="p"/>
    <Start_Date><xsl:value-of select="$p"/></Start_Date>
</xsl:template>
```

The parameter is transferred to the template "t" successfully and appears in the output, however not in the right place.
Now the problem is getting into the right context and inserting the Tag there.
Maybe someone can build on this and provide a working solution using parameters.

Comment: W3Schools are **NOT** the W3C and (rather unsurprisingly) the sentence you quote from them is incorrect.  `xsl:apply-templates` does **not** apply templates to the current element (unless you select it explicitly). If it did, you would be stuck in an endless loop. -- I am not commenting on the rest of your answer, because I did not read the question (too long).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, my bad! I changed the quote and source.